# Plotting significance stars on multiple dot & whisker plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am trying to plot significance stars (asterisks) on multiple dot & whisker plots.

Ideally, I would like the asterisks ('*' < 0.05 & '**' < 0.01) to be positioned at the top of each plot (around 1.0 on the y axis) as well as aligned and colour coded to each point on each plot. I have included some sample data as well as the code to create the plots below.

Thank you in advance!

| term | estimate | std.error | statistic | p.value | dimension | model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prec | 0.050105287 | 0.182707188 | 0.274238184 | 0.783901586 | Div | 3 |
| Prec | -0.132962824 | 0.040415646 | -3.28988493 | 0.001002284 | Div | 1 |
| Prec | -0.123040837 | 0.045041746 | -2.731706668 | 0.006300721 | Div | 2 |
| Int | 0.12331533 | 0.136372576 | 0.904253142 | 0.365861187 | Div | 3 |
| Int | 0.018063514 | 0.033165301 | 0.544650987 | 0.58599358 | Div | 1 |
| Int | -0.085348388 | 0.042054748 | -2.029459009 | 0.04241156 | Div | 2 |
| Sand | 0.3831234 | 0.238457492 | 1.606673783 | 0.108125948 | Div | 3 |
| Sand | 0.005410956 | 0.045744507 | 0.118286473 | 0.905840675 | Div | 1 |
| Sand | 0.053017872 | 0.047442281 | 1.117523679 | 0.263770481 | Div | 2 |
| Prec | 0.115600579 | 0.19879176 | 0.581515948 | 0.560892773 | MNST | 3 |
| Prec | 0.065036614 | 0.038591892 | 1.685240354 | 0.091942208 | MNST | 1 |
| Prec | -0.030596697 | 0.046203375 | -0.662217803 | 0.507831646 | MNST | 2 |
| Int | 0.027704319 | 0.148378073 | 0.186714372 | 0.851884587 | MNST | 3 |
| Int | 0.039099049 | 0.031668715 | 1.234626947 | 0.216969375 | MNST | 1 |
| Int | -0.08083994 | 0.043139342 | -1.873926127 | 0.060940608 | MNST | 2 |
| Sand | -0.142062527 | 0.259449879 | -0.547552877 | 0.583998954 | MNST | 3 |
| Sand | -0.067953721 | 0.043680281 | -1.555707058 | 0.119777768 | MNST | 1 |
| Sand | -0.185682182 | 0.048665821 | -3.815453566 | 0.000135933 | MNST | 2 |
| Prec | 0.351186494 | 0.182974321 | 1.919321203 | 0.054943696 | Var | 3 |
| Prec | 0.132487237 | 0.038579207 | 3.434161767 | 0.000594389 | Var | 1 |
| Prec | 0.000633204 | 0.047982878 | 0.013196448 | 0.989471064 | Var | 2 |
| Int | 0.213997014 | 0.136571943 | 1.566917841 | 0.117133897 | Var | 3 |
| Int | 0.099512133 | 0.031658309 | 3.143318013 | 0.001670443 | Var | 1 |
| Int | -0.018506794 | 0.044800836 | -0.413090374 | 0.679540401 | Var | 2 |
| Sand | -0.109336785 | 0.238806014 | -0.457847704 | 0.647061861 | Var | 3 |
| Sand | -0.008030686 | 0.043665926 | -0.183911951 | 0.854082529 | Var | 1 |
| Sand | -0.014314725 | 0.050540164 | -0.283234629 | 0.776996984 | Var | 2 |

```
# Load libraries
library(dotwhisker)
library(tidyverse)
rm(list=ls())

# 1. Create siginificance stars
df <- df |> 
  filter(term != "(Intercept)") |> 
  mutate(label = case_when(p.value < 0.01 ~ "**",
                           p.value < 0.05 ~ "*",
                           .default = ""))

# 2. Create plot
small_multiple(df,
               dot_args = list(aes(shape = dimension, col = dimension), size = 1.6),
               whisker_args = list(aes(linetype = dimension)),
               dodge_size = 0.7
) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 25) + ylab("") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,
             colour = "grey60",
             linetype = 2) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 25),
    axis.title = element_text(size = 30),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 25)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#FF1F5B", "#009ADE", "#FFC61E")) +
  ylim(-0.8, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `geom_text` to add your significance stars like so:

```
library(dotwhisker)
library(ggplot2)

small_multiple(df,
  dot_args = list(aes(shape = dimension, col = dimension), size = 1.6),
  whisker_args = list(aes(linetype = dimension)),
  dodge_size = 0.7
) +
  geom_text(
    data = df,
    aes(x = factor(model), y = 1, label = label, color = dimension),
    position = position_dodge(.7),
    vjust = 1,
    size = 18 / .pt
  ) +
  geom_hline(
    yintercept = 0,
    colour = "grey60",
    linetype = 2
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("#FF1F5B", "#009ADE", "#FFC61E")
  ) +
  ylim(-0.8, 1) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  ylab(NULL)
```

[image]